# Creating customised tags

Tags: xml, oracle10g

Can anyone tell me how to create customized tags using oracle XML functions.

Currently, I have written following query:

```
select xmlelement("transaction",xmlagg(xmlforest('A' as a,'B' as b))) from dual;
```

Above query is giving me output as below:

> <transaction><A>A</A><B>B</B></transaction>

I want output in following form.

> <transaction1><A>A</A><B>B</B></transaction1>

I want transaction 1, transaction 2, transaction 3, transaction..n times in my output.
Please suggest me how can I do this using oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

select xmlelement("transaction",XMLATTRIBUTES(rownum as "ID"),xmlELEMENT("A", 'A'),XMLELEMENT("B", 'B')) test from dual;

In the above query i've added an ID attribute instead of renaming the xml tags. Also the query has been modified.